# Camera application timer implementaion issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am working on custom camera application but i have no idea how to implement timer option in custom please assist me thanks ..
here is code below

```
timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"2 sec", "5 sec", "10 sec"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Timer");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("2 sec")) {

                } else if (items[item].equals("5 sec")) {

                } else if (items[item].equals("10 sec")) {

                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a **CountDownTimer** anonym to your `if-else`

- for 2 seconds with a step every second:

---

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
    //just replace 2000 for 5000 to get 5 seconds
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
           //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }

    }.start();
```

Comment: ok thanks Xoce your code is working and mTextField is define on xml or activity

Comment: remove it if you dont need to display the count down... otherwise add a textview to the xml, initialize it and use it in the CountDown

Comment: how can  we add voice like a beep beep

Comment: please open a new question

Comment: i posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361398/android-camera-application-color-effects-implements-issue